# How to import data from local text file to mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I load data to a MySQL server from a text file that is on my computer? I follow the procedure I found in this [former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579810/how-to-import-data-from-text-file-to-mysql-database), but I think it is required for you to have the data file on your server. If I try, I receive an *#1045 - Access denied for user 'learnsql'@'localhost' (using password: NO)*. I do not know if the two things are related.

I ran:

```
 LOAD DATA INFILE  'C:\Users\Me\Google Drive\dataset\userid-timestamp-artid-artname-traid-traname.tsv' INTO TABLE dataset
```

Comment: Loading data is not data mining, you know...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, opening your car and sitting in it is not driving either, but it is a quite important step in the process.

Comment: then you should have tagged the question "file", "character set", "windows", because all of these are more relevant to your question than data mining...

Answer (score 1):

The "learnsql" user must have FILE privileges.

```
grant file on *.* to user@localhost identified by 'password';
```

And MySQL must have operating system access to files, of course.

Comment: Hi, @vidario, thank you for the advice. My knowledge of MySQL is lacking, which part of your query should I edit in order to use it? Because if I try to run it as it is I receive the same error: "#1045 - Access denied for user 'learnsql'@'localhost' (using password: NO)". Also, once I have the file privileges, can I load data from my machine or do have I to upload the file on the server trough FTP?