# codeigniter import data to insert into mysql database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Is there a way to insert data from a file into mysql database in codeigniter? I am currently stuck in this part. help please. I have searched in the net but I could not understand it and i really don't know how to start this function.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the format the file is in. If it's just SQL or a CSV file, then that's quite easy to do using MySQL from the shell. Or if you have PHPMyAdmin installed, that can generally handle those formats too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CodeIgniter offers support for this. However there is a general solution  here: [How to import data from text file to mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579810/how-to-import-data-from-text-file-to-mysql-database)