# Create multiple tables with table name from multiple text files name in mysql

Tags: mysql, import

It it possible to create tables in mysql with table names from the text file.

E.g.

```
a_file.txt -> table a_file
b_file.txt -> table b_file
```

The first line in the text files should be the column name (delimited by semicolon) and the rows are in the subsequent lines.

```
CODE;TEXT;SAMPLE
1;White;
2;Black;
3;Yellow;
4;Red;
5;Blue;
6;Purple;
```

I have a folder of text files in that format.

How would that be done, if possible...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import data from text file to mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579810/how-to-import-data-from-text-file-to-mysql-database)

Comment: Not quite the same. I want to this in a bulk for all the text files in the folder.

Comment: You can probably write shell script if you are on linux environment to load all data with multiple load command at  once.

Comment: i could, if i knew howto :-) But unfortunately i don't. And I'm sitting on a windows machine...

Comment: How would you know how to create the table? Which datatype for which column and so on...Choose a programming/scripting language and do some research from there...

Comment: ok. Thanks for your comments. I look into what you have suggested

Comment: I know sqlite has a .import command that will create the table and import the data from a file. I don't know if MySQL has the some sort of thing.