# Importing CSV into MySQL with White Space

Tags: mysql, csv, import, whitespace

Anyone have any success importing a csv file into MySQL?

Here's an example csv file:

```
Full name,Source - Name
John,Youtube
Jon,FB
Jacob,Twitter
```

Here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(ID          INT        AUTO_INCREMENT          primary key,
fullname     CHAR       not null,
sourcenam1   CHAR,
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/...DDB.csv' INTO TABLE t1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(Full name, Source - Name)
```

But I get an error that says my syntax is wrong. Specifically, it is the following:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

I would like to not have to delete the column names to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql + importing a file with spaces in the column headers + how to handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611416/mysql-importing-a-file-with-spaces-in-the-column-headers-how-to-handle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names in the `LOAD DATA` column list should be the column names in the table, not the headings in the CSV file.

You also need to use the `IGNORE` option to skip over the heading line.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/...DDB.csv' INTO TABLE t1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(fullname, sourcenam1)
```

Comment: Hmmm.... When I did that, I got the following error:

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Full name' in 'field list'

NOTE: The updated code looks like this

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/...DDB.csv' INTO TABLE t1
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (`Full name`, `Source - Name`)
    set fullname = `Full name`, sourcenam1 = `Source - Name`;

Comment: What is the actual name of the column in the table?

Comment: Of the CSV?  Full name and Source - Name.  In t1 its fullname and sourcenam1.

Comment: The names in the CSV are not used for anything by MySQL.

Comment: Do I have to use the set option to indicate where fullname and sourcename1 should go?  What would that solution look like?

Comment: No, you don't. This means that the first field of the file should go in the `fullname` column of the table, the second field should go in the `sourcenam1` column. You only need `SET` if you're doing something other than just putting a CSV field directly into a table column.

Comment: Hmmm.... When I tried to view the imported data, all I see if that it is the empty set i.e.     

    mysql> SELECT * FROM Person;
    Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Note:  I got this when I ran your suggestion 

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: I've included an example csv file