# How to feed data automatically from text file into the columns of a table in MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, import, text-files

I have my java program to extract some useful data from some of the text files. Now I want that data should be put in the corresponding columns into the MySQL database. how can I do that? Please guide me.

Comment: I want to use JPA too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import data from text file to mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579810/how-to-import-data-from-text-file-to-mysql-database)

Answer (score -1):

You can create two Classes:

1. DTO (Data Transfer Object)
2. Entity

When you read the data from the text file, you can map it to your DTO class using jackson or google gson libraries. Once you create your DTO object by reading the text file, you can simply create objects of your entity class from it and call the save method of your jpa.