# How to import some columns and its data from csv file into mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I have a big `myfile.csv` file that looks like this

[image]

From this file I want to import `some` columns and obivously `rows` and its relevant `data` into `mysql` database `phpmyadmin`.

This file is located on my `local` computer, I want to import some `columns`,`rows` with `data` from that file to my `live` database.

Here is what I have tried after searching google.

I created a `table` with following columns

`id`    `name`    `email`

Then tried to run the following `query` in my `live` database

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/myfile.csv' INTO TABLE registration_no
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@col1,@col2,@col3) set id=@col1,name=@col2,email =@col3
```

**Note**

`myfile.csv` is located on my computer, in `C:` drive.

Am I running the correct `query`,is the `path` `/tmp/myfile.csv` is correct ?

Query runs but the data isn't loaded into my live `DB`, please help me, I've spent one and half day figuring this out .

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895203/11625619).

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** (preferred) Try to have only the columns(csv file) which to be imported into DB.

**ex:** If 3 columns to be imported then in your `myfile.csv` remove other unnecessary columns

**Step 2:** Since you are using a windows system make sure the path is specified properly when loading the file.

**Step 3:** If your csv has headers to skip it use `IGNORE 1 LINES.`

So, the query would be like below.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/myfile.csv' INTO TABLE registration_no
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, name, email);
```

**Step 4:** (optional) If you need to import only specific columns from csv.

**ex:** csv contains 5 columns like `id, name, reg_no, dob, email,` but need to import only 3 columns `id, name, email`. Just insert the column into a non-existing variable.

Then the query should be like

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/myfile.csv' INTO TABLE registration_no
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES #to remove first `n` rows usually used to remove header of a file.
(id, name, @dummy, @dummy, email);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,  _Step 3: If your csv has headers to skip it use IGNORE 1 LINES_ , what do you mean by that `headers` ?

Comment: In your csv file you have `headers/ column name` like license plate, vehicle type, Brand ... when you try to import the first column will also gets imported into db.

Comment: Okay, the headers will be added to the `db` like `data`, is that right ?

Comment: Yes. Just experiment yourself so that you will learn from your mistakes.

Comment: Great, let me try that, will come back to make this as checked, thank you @james

Comment: Do I need to use exactly the same `column names`, as they are in `csv` file, or I can use the name of the `columns` that are there in my own `table` ? sorry for late reply , I was travelling !

Comment: *(id, name, email);* this is the table.column_name. from csv it will just match based on the order.

Comment: I'm running the following query but this is not loading the data.  `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\carseller.csv' INTO TABLE registration_no
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(id, license_plate,vehicle_type,brand,trade_name,apk_expiration,design,no_of_seats,@dummy1,@dummy2,@dummy3,@dummy4,@dummy5, @dummy6, @dummy7);
`

Comment: after column `I` in `csv` file,(see above image of csv) I don't want to load that data, that is why I have used `@dummy` for further 7 columns,

Comment: no error, the query run `successfully`, but the `data` is not imported

Comment: use should use forward slash when denoting the file path

Comment: my table looks like this `id`, `license_plate` , `vehicle_type`, `brand`, `trade_name`, `apk_expiration`, `design`, `no_of_seats`

Comment: `C:/carseller.csv` forward slash

Comment: Okay, just take a part of csv into new one by having only those columns before `I` then about one or two rows of data then try it out.

Comment: that is not working, I tried to make a `new` file with those columns with some `rows` but data is still not loading

Comment: I have `table.id`, and the `csv` don't have that `id` as column, although the rows are `numbered` in csv, will that make any problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199665/discussion-between-james-and-contributor).