# [Perl]read text file with delimiter and insert into mysql table in perl 5.10

Tags: mysql, perl

I have text file(employeedata.txt) with values like this :

```
ABC#VVV#JHY#ABC#VVV#JHY#ABC#VVV#JHY#ABC#VVV
BBN#NJU#NULL#ABC#VVV#JHY#ABC#VVV#JHY#ABC#OLJ
ABC#BYR#MPL#ABC#VVV#JHY#ABC#TGB#JHY#ABC#NULL
NMP#JDC#NULL#ABC#VVV#JHY#ABC#XCD#JHY#ABC#NULL
UJK#SAB#NULL#ABC#VVV#JHY#ABC#NBG#JHY#ABC#MPL
```

my text file contains 5,000 lines and I have a Table called `Employee` with values like this:

```
id|EmployeLastName|EmployeFirstName|EmployeeAddress
```

In my file text, in each line, i have `EmployeLastName` in the first position, `EmployeFirstName` in the fourth position, `EmployeeAddress` in the last position

Example :

```
EmployeLastName#VVV#JHY#EmployeFirstName#VVV#JHY#ABC#VVV#JHY#ABC#EmployeeAddress
```

Now I want to read text file line by line and insert into table `Employee` by using perl 5.10.

I am a novice in perl. How can do it?

Comment: First you need perl and mysql see https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-dbi/ and then you need the mysql script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579810/how-to-import-data-from-text-file-to-mysql-database

Comment: Why don't you use `LOAD DATA INFILE` instead of `perl`?

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to do some reading on [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql) driver to get a grip on the code provided bellow -- it is best invested time to work with DB.

NOTE: in this piece of code I read data from internal block **__DATA__**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;

my $debug = 0;

my @fields = qw(id last first address); # Field names in Database
my(%record,$rv);

my $hostname = 'db_server_1';           # Database server name
my $database = 'db_employees';          # Database name
my $table    = 'db_table';              # Table name
my $port     = '3306';                  # Database port [default]

# Define DSN
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$hostname;port=$port";
# Connect to Database
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password, {RaiseError => 1});
# Define query
my $stq = qq(INSERT INTO $table (id,last,first,address) VALUES(?,?,?,?););
# Prepare query
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($stq);

$dbh->begin_work();                     # Ok, we will do insert in one transaction

my $skip = <DATA>;                      # We skip header in data block

while( <DATA> ) {
    @record{@fields} = split /#/;       # Fill the hash with record data

    print Dumper(\%row) if $debug;      # Look at hash in debug mode

    $rv = $sth->execute(@record{@fields});  # Execute query with data

    print $DBI::errstr if $rv < 0;      # If error lets see ERROR message 
}

$dbh->commit();                         # Commit the transaction
$dbh->disconnect();                     # Disconnect from DataBase


__DATA__
id#EmployeLastName#EmployeFirstName#EmployeeAddress
1#Alexander#Makedonsky#267 Mozarella st., Pizza, Italy
2#Vladimir#Lenin#12 Glinka st., Moscow, Italy
3#Donald#Trump#765 Tower ave., Florida, USA
4#Angela#Merkel#789 Schulstrafe st., Berlin, Germany
```

You can read data from a file with following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $debug = 1;

my @fields = qw(id last first address); # Field names in Database
my(%record);

my $filename = shift
    or die "Provide filename on command line";

open DATA, "< $filename"
     or die "Could not open $filename";

while( <DATA> ) {
   @record{@fields} = split /#/;

   print Dumper(\%record) if $debug;
}

close DATA;
```

As you very fresh in *Perl* programming then you probably should start from [Learning Perl](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/lperl/index.htm), then move on [Programming Perl](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/prog/index.htm), when you get in *trouble* visit [Perl Cookbook](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/cookbook/index.htm) and if you decided to dive into database programming [Programming the Perl DBI](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/dbi/index.htm)

Comment: NOTE: if your table has fields with specification **uniq** you will get errors on duplicate record insertion. You need to do some reading on DB table creation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html (please keep in mind that there might be difference between versions of MySQL -- look into documentation for your version to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 1):

Well it is nice to know *Perl* and *DBI* driver programming. But in your particular case you could load data from a file directly by utilizing *MySQL* commands.

[Loading Data into a Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/loading-tables.html)

Sometimes it is much much easier than it looks at first sight.